# Do I have memory leak in this JNI code?

Tags: java, c++, memory, java-native-interface

I need to get jByteArray from std::string and return it to Java from C++ code. Does it is correct code for returning jByteArray or I need to release something?

```
JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_my_project_byteArray0
(JNIEnv * env, jobject jo)
{
    std::string str = get_something().string();

    jbyteArray ba = env->NewByteArray(str.size());
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(ba, 0, str.size(), (jbyte*)str.c_str());

    return ba;
}
```

Comment: You're returning back to Java, so there's no need for you to delete the local reference to the `byte[]`, if that's what you're asking. The situations in which you typically delete local references are when you're creating them inside a loop, or when your function runs in a purely native thread. In general if you want to find memory leaks in C++ code I suggest you use some kind of tool, e.g. [LLVM's LeakSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LeakSanitizer.html).

Comment: @Michael, thanks, I think you could publish your comment as answer